# Get the value without the bracket

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
NSString *urlPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false",coordinate1.latitude,coordinate1.longitude,coordinate2.latitude,coordinate2.longitude];

//NSLog(@"the url for searching is : %@",urlPath);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSNumber *results = [[[[object valueForKey:@"routes"]valueForKey:@"legs"]valueForKey:@"distance"]valueForKey:@"value"];

NSLog(@"Count %@",results);
```

The result comes out as :

```
(
    (
        12078
    )
)
```

is it possible to just get the number out ?

Comment: Can you post your code again in a code block so we can read it?

Comment: You're not getting a number, you're getting an array of arrays.

Comment: [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) may save you some time.

Comment: How about `results[0][0]`?

Comment: You can simplify your dictionary lookup, too: `object[@"routes"][@"legs"][@"distance"][@"value"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Google API for maps I can tell, that routes contains legs and legs have distance attribute.

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "routes": [ {
    "summary": "I-40 W",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
      },
      ...
      ... additional steps of this leg
    ...
    ... additional legs of this route
      "duration": {
        "value": 74384,
        "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      },
      "start_location": {
        "lat": 35.4675602,
        "lng": -97.5164276
      },
      "end_location": {
        "lat": 34.0522342,
        "lng": -118.2436849
      },
      "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
      "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
    } ],
```

So the distance for the first leg of the first route should be:

```
NSNumber *distance = object[@"routes"][0][@"legs"][0][@"distance"][@"value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't save it as `NSNumber` since it is a string value.
Use `NSNumberFormatter` to save `NSString` as `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *results = [f numberFromString:[[[[object valueForKey:@"routes"] valueForKey:@"legs"] valueForKey:@"distance"] valueForKey:@"value"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.9715,77.045&destination=12.7152,77.888&sensor=false"];

//NSLog(@"the url for searching is : %@", urlPath);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *results = [[[[object valueForKey:@"routes"] valueForKey:@"legs"] valueForKey:@"distance"] valueForKey:@"value"];

NSLog(@"Count %@", results);
NSLog(@"Count %@", results[0][0]);
```